Are questions relating specifically to Ghidra on-topic?
As a newcomer to RE I recently asked a question about something that I was not understanding. I mentioned that I was using Ghidra and didn't understand why something wasn't working the way that I expected it to, although the answer to my question may or may not be more about understanding in general rather than a specific tool (I don't know because I don't know the answer and if I did know then I wouldn't be asking the question).
I was quickly rudely shut down and told to ask in the Ghidra GitHub issues page.
I then saw another Ghidra question being similarly shut down by the same person in the same way.
Am I correct in thinking that this person is being rude and going on a rampage against newbies who use Ghidra, or are these questions genuinely inappropriate to post here?
(Also, what happened to "don't bite the newbies"?)

Hi there, I'll side with julian, but also will note that I am guilty of having misjudged similar questions simply on account of the fact that they sounded more like a Java problem (Ghidra plugin) than an RCE problem. So there's a certain line there. But I would still probably say that such a question is on-topic here, if the nature of the question is less about Java and more about Ghidra and the internals that cause the trouble.

@0xC0000022L Yeah that makes sense, the difference between "tech support" questions for users not knowing how to install/set up the software, and questions relating to users not understanding what they're seeing or what they need to do when they use the software even if the "what they're seeing/doing" is specific to a particular piece of software.

Ghidra questions are on-topic. This includes questions about the tool itself. There is nothing wrong with also opening an issue at their GitHub repo, and if an answer is provided there please share it here as well.

Am I correct in thinking that this person is being rude

Yes, you are correct. If you see a post where it's clear someone is being rude, please flag it to bring it to our attention.

Thank you. Answer was flagged for tone but I wasn't sure if I was nevertheless wrong for asking here (just because they're rude about it doesn't necessarily mean that the question is not nevertheless off-topic).

@MichealJohnson thanks for asking the question. The particular user has shown some irate behavior in recent weeks, so please don't take it personally. While we are trying to keep things civil, it sometimes takes time. And flagging helps us to see the issues, so flag away ... just as julian suggests.
